# Catching Window Resize

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, events, window

I'm trying to resize a graphics device buffer when the window is resized, but I have no luck in detecting the event.

This is C++ Windows programming. I tried:

```
            while(WM_QUIT != msg.message){
                if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
                    switch(msg.message){
                    case WM_SIZE:
                        return; //<-- If the program closes because of this return, then I know I found the right statements.
                    }
                    //TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    //DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }else{
                    poly.setConstantBuffer(space.getCamera());
                    poly.draw(iSize);

                    graphics.render();
                }
            }
```

It is not returning, so that means that is not correct. What is the right way to catch the resize event?

Comment: Can you post the full code, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be handling messages in your window procedure, not in the message loop. `PeekMessage` does not return sent messages, and `WM_SIZE` is a sent message.

Comment: I didnt realize there was a switch available for us to add to. I was in the wrong function. Thanks both of you.

Comment: On a side note, what useful thing could I do in the message loop?

Comment: Pump messages, and exit. Games and full screen graphics apps can also do their rendering in the loop too.

Comment: @PhaniRithvij You should get an introductory Windows programming book to explain concepts like window procedure and message loop.

Comment: @PhaniRithvij Please ask a separate question instead of trying to hijack an existing one.

Answer (score 3):

`WM_SIZE` is not the only message sent to a window during a resize.  You need to uncoment the calls to `TranslateMessage()` and `DispatchMessage()` so those other messages get processed.  And your window's mssage dispatch procedure needs to pass unhandled messages to `DefWindowProc()` for default processing.  Are you doing all of that?

Comment: I had whatever the samples for DX had. The MSDN was not clear when I was reading it, so I thought I waas suppose to replace the translate msg part.